# Dynamically creating a getter that returns a property of the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a getter within an object that returns the appropriate type of a field.

I got it working with this:

```
const getType = field => ({
  email: "email",
  telephone: "tel",
  get type() {
    return this[field] || "text";
  }
});
```

My only issue here is that this is a function that returns an object.

[image: Edit blazing-pond-8cxlq]

I'm trying to take a slightly different approach, by creating a dynamic computed property based on the passed parameter.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
const getType = {
  email: "email",
  telephone: "tel",
  get [type]() {
    return this[type] || "text";
  }
};
```

But this throws an error, `Error: type is not defined`.

[image: Edit purple-microservice-furqu]

Is what I am trying to do possible in JavaScript?

I'm aware I can just do something like,

```
const fieldsMatrix = {
  email: 'email',
  telephone: 'tel',
}

['email', 'username'].map(field => <input type={fieldsMatrix[prop] || 'text'} />)
```

But that's not what I'm asking in the question.

Comment: Why not just define a method that takes property name as an argument and returns the value of that property if it exists in the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) to intercept all attempts to get any property.

```js
const getType = new Proxy({
  email: "email",
  telephone: "tel",
}, {
  get(target, prop, receiver) {
    return target[prop] || "text";
  }
});
console.log(getType.email);
console.log(getType.somethingElse);
```

You can also define a function on the object instead.

```js
const types = {
  email: "email",
  telephone: "tel",
  getType(type) {
    return this[type] || "text";
  }
};
console.log(types.getType('email'));
console.log(types.getType('somethingElse'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do

```
const getType = field => {
  const data = {
    email: "email",
    telephone: "tel",
  };
  const result = data[field] || "text";
  Object.defineProperty(data,field,{
    get:()=>result,
  })
  return data;
}
```